# Rails associations can't mass-assign foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, activemodel, mass-assignment

Maybe I am doing it wrong but here is my issue:

```
@restaurant = current_user.restaurants.build(params[:restaurant])
```

This builds a new restaurant object where the user_id is set to the `current_user.id`. This only works if you set `attr_accessible :user_id` in the Restaurant Model. If not you get a

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes:
user_id
```

What I want is to have the `user_id` defined via `.build` but at the same time I do not want the `attr_accessible :user_id` because then it is possible for someone to set the user_id of this record to some other user's id, which would be bad!!

I thought the foreign keys were excluded from this Mass Assignment Security and were enforced if you create a new object via the association `.build` or `.create` methods.

Any suggestions? I dont want to go back to

```
@restaurant = current_user.restaurants.build(params[:restaurant])
@restaurant.user = current_user
```

because that kind of defeats the purpose of `.build`

Comment: are you sure there is no `id` in your params?

Comment: yes! no id in the params hash

Comment: Are you using Rails 3.2.0.rc1? That's a know bug https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4051 (resolved)

Comment: @Delba thx! yes i am. should have checked the rails issues first. sorry folks

Comment: @patrickdet ah ah! I am a bit ashamed of myself but... may I put this into an answer so you can accept it lol?

Comment: @Delba, you've provided a valuable answer, don't be ashamed!

Comment: @patrickdet rhaaa easy points! Thanks

Comment: @Delba yeah no shame in that! it really helped me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Rails 3.2.0.rc1? That's a know bug github.com/rails/rails/issues/4051 (resolved)